# My first Java game - most efficient way to exit?

Tags: java, performance, class, oop, object

I am fairly new to Java and have built my first basic character-battle game, but I am not sure how to expand upon this. If my goal is to practice object orientation and classes what are your recommendations for things to focus on? I appreciate any advice!

My current largest issue is I can't find a way to simplify exiting the game when someone hits the 'x' button. I have currently coded each exit individually, but I am hoping there is some way to exit any time any 'x' is pressed? or even just a cleaner way to handle it.

```
public class GameFile extends JFrame
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String name;
        int clicked, playAgain = 0;

        while (playAgain == 0)
        {
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome! What is your name?");
            if (name != null)
            {
                GameCharacter player = new GameCharacter(10, name, CharacterType.PLAYER);
                GameCharacter enemy = new GameCharacter(10, "the Evil Wizard", CharacterType.ENEMY);
                clicked = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                        "Hi " + player.getName() + "! Get ready to battle you opponent!", " ",
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                if (clicked == 0)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        String[] moveChoices = { "Attack", "Use Potion(" + player.getPotions() + ")" };
                        int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What would you like to do?", " ",
                                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, moveChoices,
                                moveChoices[0]);
                        if (choice == 0)
                        {
                            player.attack(enemy);
                            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                    "You attacked " + enemy.getName() + "! They have " + enemy.getHealthPoints()
                                            + " health left.",
                                    " ", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE) != 0)
                            {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (choice == 1)
                        {
                            player.usePotion();
                            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                    "You used a potion! You have " + player.getHealthPoints() + " health.", " ",
                                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE) != 0)
                            {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        if (enemy.getHealthPoints() > 0)
                        {
                            if ((enemy.getHealthPoints() < 10) && (enemy.getPotions() > 0))
                            {
                                enemy.usePotion();
                                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                        enemy.getName() + " used a potion! They have " + enemy.getHealthPoints()
                                                + " health.",
                                        " ", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE) != 0)
                                {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                enemy.attack(player);
                                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                        enemy.getName() + " attacked you! You have " + player.getHealthPoints()
                                                + " health left.",
                                        " ", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE) != 0)
                                {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } while (player.getHealthPoints() > 0 && enemy.getHealthPoints() > 0);
                    if (player.getHealthPoints() <= 0)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you lose!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Great job " + player.getName() + ", you win!");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            playAgain = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to play again?", " ",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess you used `System.exit` more often than most programmers in their whole carrier. Is exiting the JVM really the thing your players need most?

Comment: You are nesting so many conditionals that the code becomes hard to read. Instead of `if (name != null) { ... } else { System.exit(0); }` you could do `if (name == null) { System.exit(0); } ...`. This might also help you find a solution to your problem.

Comment: Consider using some **OOP**. Abstract your game into classes, objects, methods etc. It will be so much easier to get an overview of the situation without all those nested `if`s and `while`s and `else`s. Especially, try to use an own method for each sub-logic of your game.

Comment: @Bubletan thank you! I was able to remove 2 statements like that, it helped a lot with the messy and excessive nesting.

Comment: @Zabuza Thank you, his is great advice but Im unsure of how to go about it. I currently have my characters as well as their basic actions (use potion, attack, setHealthPoints, etc) as methods in my GameCharacter class but am unsure what else could be turned into other methods or objects. OOP is actually what I am doing this project to try and practice but I worry Im still keeping things way too procedural and am totally missing the mark with that.

Comment: Start by moving your logic in `main` into several methods. It does so many things at once, I see character creation, movement logic, input parsing, attack logic, item logic, exit logic. You could create methods for all of them. And in a good OOP game you would have interfaces for everything. And the logic would be separated through behavior and controller objects.

Answer (score 0):

The context is that you appear to have the main game control logic in a `while` loop that offers the user the choice of playing again.  But you seem to be calling `System.exit` in lots of places ... and if you do that, the user won't have the option of playing again.

I think ... maybe ... that you should not be "exiting" at all.  Certainly, not if you want to let the player to play another game.  So, maybe the question you should really asking is to how to abandon the current game without exiting the program.  For example, you could break from the (inner) loop, or you could refactor the code so that each game is a method call.

In short:

- If you really want the program to exit, then what you are doing is efficient, though ugly.
- If you don't want to exit, then there are other ways to do it correctly.  You should not be calling System.exit at all.

Comment: Thank you! I want allow the user to hard-exit when they click the corner 'x', so I am okay with not asking to play again. My concern is more with how messy my excessive System.exit calls cause my code to appear. Im hoping for a way to decrease or at least organize them in a better manner. I also am thinking that issue may be due to the way I've written the code itself. I have been attempting to practice OOP but other than the basic actions and character, I have struggled to put anything else into methods/objects/classes.  Thanks again- I am fairly new and really appreciate the input and advice